# Getting status codes from a server with an IP address and port number in Java

Tags: java

I was able to do this with the Socket class. However I wanted to get something along the lines of what HttpUrlConnection has to offer.

Right now I am doing the following:

```
public void checkServerStatus(String IP_ADDRESS, int PORT, String SERVER_NAME) {

        try(Socket s = new Socket(IP_ADDRESS, PORT)) {

            System.out.println("Connection good on "+SERVER_NAME);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("There was an IO error "+ ex);
        }catch(SecurityException ex) {
            System.out.println("There was an security error "+ ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){
            System.out.println("There was an IllegalArgumentException "+ ex);
        }
    }
```

However I would like do something like:

```
public static String getStatus(String url) throws IOException {

        String result = "";
        try {
            URL siteURL = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) siteURL.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();

            int code = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (code == 200) {
                result = "Green";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = "->Red<-";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

However with only the IP address and the Port I want to check.

After reading the URL API I cannot do that and HttpUrlConnection is dependent on URL.

I am trying to create a server health status type of program, and if there is a problem it returns a code.

Comment: You cannot get a response code from a Socket but you can check if it is online by checking if it is reachable. This can be done with [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int))

Comment: What `PORT` are you connecting to, and what protocol is spoken on that port?

Comment: @Kenney I am checking port 80 for now. However I might want to change that.

Comment: @bwfcwalshy thank you. I have used that class in the past but it is still accomplishing what I am already doing with the above code. I suppose what I have will have to do and if there is an error I will have to use curl commands. I just wanted to create an application that we could use that could speed up finding the issue.

Comment: Since you're talking to port 80, the protocol is HTTP, so you can use the HttpURLConnection: construct the URL like `"http://" + SERVER_NAME  +"/"`. Alternatively, using the socket, you can send it a `"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + SERVER_NAME + "\r\n\r\n"` - the first line you get back looks like `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` (for "green" status). You're not only checking if the *server* is up, but also if the *service* running on `PORT` is working.